# Laravel Hosted in Subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

A client has requested a website built and now that it has been built, they've requested it be hosted alongside their existing website but in a subdirectory (`example.com/example/path`).

What I'm dealing with now is figuring out the required apache rules to host this correctly. I've uploaded the entire project structure to that directory. Within the public directory (`/example/path/public`) I have the following .htaccess file (henceforth I'll refer to this as the Laravel .htaccess):

```apache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /example/path

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


    # Serve Cached Page If Available...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page-cache/pc__index__pc.html -f
    RewriteRule .? page-cache/pc__index__pc.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page-cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
    RewriteRule . page-cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|otf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have added the `RewriteBase` line based on me trying to find a solution to this.

Within the base .htaccess file (`/example/path/.htaccess`), I have the following:

```apache
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /example/path /home/www/<user>/html/example/path
    <Directory "/home/www/<user>/html/example/path">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is however that this returns an internal server error. I've tried other potential solutions that don't use `Alias` that instead return 40X errors.

I need to be able to have the Laravel site fully working when a user visits `example.com/example/path`. I've tried numerous solutions over the past 90 minutes and none have worked.

What is the *correct* solution to my situation?

Comment: Unfortuntely I think the *correct* solution is to never host a Laravel app under a publicly browseable docroot ... Anything else is a [hacky security risk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#directory-configuration).  You should probably inform your client of that, and suggest they host it on a different vhost.

Comment: "*The problem is however that this returns an internal server error.*" - what is the error?  Your PHP/Apache logs will tell you more detail about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In public folder we have hosted 8 platforms and each platform's root directory we have this `.htaccess` configuration. hope this helps you.

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
 
    <ifmodule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </ifmodule>
     
    RewriteEngine On
     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
 
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: how do you hide the .env file and the storage/logs

Comment: It is automatically hidden from the server (we use a2 hosting) we did not required any extra configuration for that. And also I did not faced this situation yet before. I also saw many people faced this issue. But in our case these directories are not accessible. It will show 404.

Comment: Hi again, @Snapey

I just tested in our server actually this .htaccess configuration is also hiding the `.env` and also `storage/logs` . This htaccess was written my one of our colleague so i was not aware that this file is helping both way.

This is the line to that is hiding `.env` and `storage/logs`


✅ `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1`

Comment: Hi, this almost works perfectly, however I cannot access anything in the public directory. Would this be something missing in this `.htaccess` file or the one in the public directory?

Comment: We have 2 .htaccess, 1 is in root directory of laravel project which is custom and another one is in laravel's public directory which is laravel default ..... for example: 1.  domain.com/site/.htaccess 2. domain.com/site/public/.htaccess

Comment: Make sure you added the file correctly. code above will go inside `public_html/my_project/.htaccess`

Comment: Yes, I understood all of that. The issue I'm having with what you've provided though is that anything located in public is inaccessible. I'll assume this is based on my client's server settings though as their root 404 page is the one to display and not any defined in the Laravel application.

Comment: I can access other files in public directory without any issue's. The current issue you are facing after using `.htaccess` in root, that could be some kind of client side server settings.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently too. My client had their Wordpress set to resolve at as the Document root (/var/www/html), but they also wanted their Laravel app "installed" in a subfolder of Wordpress and named "hq"

This however would be a security problem, because we only want Laravel's Public folder exposed, and not the application files.  To solve this problem, I used the power of symbolic links!

The Laravel app was placed below the Document root at:

```
/var/www/laravel
```

I then exposed Laravel's public folder in the DocumentRoot with the command "ln -s symlinkLocation symbolic-link-name"

```
ln -s /var/www/laravel/public /var/www/html/hq
```

In the above line, you can see that "hq" is not an actual folder, but instead a symlink to /var/www/laravel/public

(which is where Laravel's index.php entry point is, the css, js etc)
[image]

Here is what the symbolic link looks like:
[image]

I also made a symbolic link to the storage folder:

```
ln -s /var/www/laravel/public/ /var/www/laravel/storage/app/public
```

Which accomplishes what "php artisan storage:link" accomplishes.

For reference, here is what my laravel .htaccess looks like:

The .htaccess in /var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess was

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

create a htaccess file in root directory of project

**and add the following lines :**

```
#disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

#PROTECT ENV FILE
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

#PROTECT htaccess FILE
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```